# ExtJs and Symfony - Your Experiences

Tags: symfony1, extjs

Not so much of a question as such but I am about to start a project using Extjs (www.extjs.com) and Symfony (www.symfony-project.org).

I would like to know about your experiences. I.e. any hurdles you had to overcome, any technical triumphs. Practices you implemented to make development with both of the frameworks easier, useful plugins, things you would change if you were going to use both of them together again etc.

Thanks very much! Have a good day.

Comment: This should probably be a CW.

Comment: a CW? please enlighten me. thanks :-)

Comment: A Community Wiki question :-) It's used where it's probably not possible to choose 1 'correct' answer from the ones provided.  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts for details.  You can edit your question and check the "Community Wiki" box.

Comment: Ok thanks. I've edited it to be included in the CW. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to symfony, you are all alone. You pretty much start building everything on your own. Altough if you were to do something with jQuery you may hit some plugins already out there. Needless to say ExtJS is not very handy, so it will be more time consuming.
ExtJS is great but you should avoid if you are not up to build up a desktop-level web application most probably with a team of developers! It is far more complex, more than most projects need.